# Differences between nuget-packing a csproj vs. nuspec

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Recently, I started to pack nuget packages out of my several projects. First I started with the Package Explorer application. It is a nice tool, but it's less useful if you do continuous integration. Then I looked into specifying the *nuspec* template file, and passing changing data, e.g. version number, as command line arguments. Later, I wondered how to define the nuget package dependencies. As it turns out, the nuget.exe already does this based on the *package.config* if you specify a *csproj*. Moreover, it extracts relevant data like Author, Version, Copyright right from the assembly info. What I'm missing right now is the ability to specify a licenseUrl in the command line. But I wanted the question to be more generic. And so I'm asking:

**What is the prefered way to pack nuget packages?**

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Here's a little-known fact: **you can combine both**!
Target a csproj file, and make sure there's a nuspec file in the same directory with the same name as the csproj file. NuGet will merge the two during package creation.

So in short: target `<ProjectName>.csproj`, optionally add a corresponding *[tokenized](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Replacement_Tokens)* `<ProjectName>.nuspec` file to be used as metadata by NuGet.exe.

It saves you from managing output location, dependencies, version, and other stuff that can be derived from the project.

Comment: Hi Xavier, thanks for pointing this out :) I already found this [blog post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/04/easy-way-to-publish-nuget-packages-with.html) which also suggest this approach. Is this also described in the book I got from you on the WarmCrocConf?;) Great presentation btw!;)

Comment: Hi Matthias, thank you! If I'm not mistaken, it is mentioned on page 71 :)

Comment: is it possible to get the version from the assemblyinfo AND have a nuspec? 

i do want the nuspec author and releasenotes bits, but it seems then i'd have to handle the version tag in the nuspec as well as the assemblyinfo

Comment: @JohnKorsnes you tried using the nuspec with prepopulated values for author and releasenotes etc, whilst leaving the version tag tokenized? (<version>$version$</version>)

Comment: I believe I only tried omitting it, but that did not help (as the pack fails). Will see if leaving it tokenized helps

Comment: A note for those using Mono, NuGet.exe doesn't support packing by targeting a csproj (as of 3.3). There's plans to make it happen though. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1946#issuecomment-186005540

Comment: Can confirm that using $version$ seems to work. Nice find.

Comment: I also had issues getting $version$ working. I was able to get it working by doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48384248/279516

Answer (score 23):

With a .csproj for Visual Studio 2017, you don't need a .nuspec file. You can actually add the values directly to your csproj and it will pick them up.

Right click the project in Visual Studio, Edit xxxxx.csproj. Notepad works fine too.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    <authors>Subtracts</authors>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net452</TargetFrameworks>
    <AssemblyName>Checkout.net</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>Checkout.net</PackageId>

...

</Project>
```

p.s. Since I don't have sufficient reputation to comment, I am leaving an answer instead of a comment on Xavier's answer. :)

Comment: When you want to edit the `.csproj` file from Visual Studio you need to select _Unload Project_ before the _Edit csproj_ option becomes available.

Comment: @Chrono That depends on the project type, it's not necessary for .NET Core and .NET Standard projects.

Comment: @Chrono @Stijn It's not necessary when you are using the new csproj format (i.e. starts with `<Project Sdk...>`). You can use the new csproj format with .net framework projects, including WPF and WinForms projects.

Answer (score 20):

For simple packages you can directly create the packages off `.csproj` or `.vbproj`. But for more advance packages, especially when you need to pull in custom files into your package, you need to use `.nuspec`. I usually start off with the csproj and move to nuspec as needed. You can always get the nuspec using the command `nuget spec` on the csproj.

https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package

You can specify any of the properties including `licenseUrl` using the `Properties` parameter to `nuget pack`

```
nuget pack -properties licenseUrl=http://blah
```

Answer (score 13):

With .NET Core as of February 2018 you'll need to supply a `.nuspec` file for any more than the basic spec file properties.

But the `dotnet pack` command will not use the `.nuspec` file unless you add `<NuspecFile>relative path to nuspec</NuspecFile>` to the `.csproj` file.

See https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2170

Most packages can now be made without a `.nuspec` file. The thing to watch is the dependencies. You may need to add a `PrivateAssets` element to some that are tools, like `msbump` and um, SpecFlow maybe.

```
<PackageReference Include="msbump" Version="2.3.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

This stops this package dependency "flowing" to the dependencies of your package.

Also worth reading about specifying versions in the most flexible way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#floating-versions

And range syntax.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#references-in-project-files-packagereference